# BlueMix - Can't access virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

I'm running on BlueMix some test VM. Since today, it is impossible to even connect to the virtual machines (ssh, or running applications).

In the bluemix console, machines are running. I even tested to reboot one, without success.

Any idea or problem currently running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you able to ssh in before?  Can you try using your ssh key with another VM to make sure its not an issue with your key

Comment: Yes, I was able to access, and all the vm were unreacheable. It was an IBM "maintenance". As VM are beta, my IBM representative told me they can suspend the service at any time to work on the platform, without any announcement. Blackout duration was at least 6 hours.

Comment: Can you accept the answer so we can close out the question?